# json in perl deserialization length count doesn't work

Tags: php, json, perl

How do iterate through a deserialized json string? I can't get the right number of values right now it doesn't count right.

```
my $list = request("http://localhost/getjson.php");                             
my $deserialize = from_json( $list );
print Dumper($deserialize);
$VAR1 = [
          'ab',
          'cc',
          'de',
          'aer',
          'ffe',
          'cer',
          'dad',
          'efef',
          'afaf',
          'ege',
          'grsc',
          'cegg',
          'cegg',          
          'cegg/aaa.html',
          'eggt',
          'ttt'
        ];
print length($deserialize);
13 ?? it should say 16
```

Comment: Is it a typo that you forgot the `$` sigil on `deserialize`, or is that in your actual code?

Comment: Yet sorry typo fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting back an array reference not an array. You need to dereference the value.

```
my @array = @$deserialize; # or @{ $deserialize }
print scalar @array;
```

Moreover, if you want to iterate over the array you can just use `for`

```
for (@$deserialize) { 
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

From [perldoc -f length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html):

```
This function cannot be used on an entire array or hash to find
out how many elements these have.  For that, use "scalar
@array" and "scalar keys %hash", respectively.
```

You cannot use `length` to find out the size of an array. To do that, use the advice above.

Your bug gives you a false value because you are taking the length of the array reference, which in string context will be something like `ARRAY(0x22d0a88)`, which in your case seemed to be 13 characters long. E.g. the equivalent of:

```
print length "ARRAY(0x22d0a88)";
```

As a curious side note, if you would do `length(@array)`, it will actually return the length of the length of the array. E.g. an array of size 16 would return 2, because the string `"16"` is two characters long.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually working with reference to the results. Since JSON can contain all sorts of different results, decode_json won't return a list specifically.

So you need to dereference the variable that you have: $deserialize

Additionally, you don't really want to be using the length function. If you print the integer value (or scalar value) of an array, it will return it's size.

So here's what you want:

```
my $list = request("http://localhost/getjson.php");                             
my $deserialize = from_json( $list );
print scalar (@{$deserialize});
```

That will print the size of the array.

If you want to just start by working with an array you can do:

```
my $list = request("http://localhost/getjson.php");                             
my $deserialize = from_json( $list );
my @json_array = @{$deserialize});
print scalar (@json_array);
```

Comment: `int(@array)` does not do what you think it does. The idiomatic way to get the array size is `scalar @array`. `int` works because it puts the array in scalar context, so you're doing e.g. `int(16)`, which of course returns the integer portion of 16.

Comment: Interesting, I always knew that scalar was the better way to do it, but I always just preferred the ease of typing "int" instead. I'll start doing it the proper way from now on.

Comment: There are many ways to impose scalar context. For example: `my $size = @array`.

Comment: You might also be interested to know that the curly brackets are not required when there is no ambiguity in the dereferencing: `@$aref` is equivalent to `@{$aref}`. And prettier, and easier to type.